# initial access token for gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

Is there an automated way to get a personal access token for the root user of gitlab after deploying?  Trying to automate some post-deployment API configuration, but currently it requires creating a personal access token manually.

Comment: Would https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/26344#note_53318722 help?

Comment: @VonC - no... to use the API requires a token.  It's a chicken and egg scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#programmatically-creating-a-personal-access-token) finally.

```sh
gitlab-rails runner "token = User.find_by_username('automation-bot').personal_access_tokens.create(scopes: [:read_user, :read_repository], name: 'Automation token'); token.set_token('token-string-here123'); token.save!"
```